# Putting a video to pause state before playing

Tags: ios, ipad, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am using MVMoviePlayer to play videos in the app. Right now, a black screen comes after taping the play button and the video starts playing. But, the black screen is casing some discofort from the user end point of view. So, i want to start the video from a paused state.
In order to do this, i thought of putting the player to paused state before playing it..

Is there a way to do this???

Answer (score 4):

You can hide your `MPMoviePlayer` until that annoying black flicker is gone.

To ensure that the black flicker is gone, you can check if the `MPMoviePlayer`'s `loadState` is 3 ( which means `MPMovieLoadStatePlayable` | `MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK` ) and `playbackState` is 1 (which means `MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying`)

First hide your `MPMoviePlayer`:

```
yourMPMoviePlayer.view.hidden = YES;
```

Just add an observer to be notified when loadState changes:

```
[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserver:self
                                       selector:@selector(loadStateChanged:) 
                                           name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                         object:nil];
```

And make your MPMoviePlayer visible again when you are notified and conditions are met:

```
- (void)loadStateChanged:(NSNotification *)sentNotification
{
    if (player.loadState == (MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK | MPMovieLoadStatePlayable) && player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying)
        yourMPMoviePlayer.view.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: you should really be using the enum identifiers, not their values: if (player.loadState == (MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK | MPMovieLoadStatePlayable) && player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying);

Comment: You are right, but there is no enum like 3 for MPMoviePlaybackState. You gotta Bitwise OR them (MPMovieLoadStatePlayable | MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK). I just been lazy.

Comment: perfectly worked by adding  if (player.loadState == (MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK | MPMovieLoadStatePlayable)