# How to preload my movie before playing it ( MPMoviePlayerController )

Tags: objective-c, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

i would like to preload my MPMoviePlayerController, the problem is that MPMoviePlayerController is taking too much time to get ready so the loading icon is displaying then the video is displayed, if i play another video after it is played directly but not the first time... :(

i know there is this : MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification But i don't know how it works actually.

This is my code  :

```
- (void) startSlideShow:(NSString *)nameFile
{    
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:nameFile];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = 
    [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayer];

    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDuration:0.5];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

    [[self.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
   }


-(void)moviePlayBackDidFinish: (NSNotification*)notification
{ 
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [notification object];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self      
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:moviePlayer];

    if ([moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
    {
       [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    [self checkResources];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can speed up video loading process. Only thing you can do is to load video sooner than displaying it.

For player state notifications, see my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9073946/624808

Comment: perfect it kind of work, but at least i don't have the loading icon :)

Comment: But there is still few seconds of loading ( even if we don't see the loading icon ) how can i make it start directly... finally why it is taking time at the first video ? because it init the MPMoviePlayerController and the others doesnt need to init it or what ? :s

Comment: You can use UIActivityIndicatorView as loading icon until video shows up.

Comment: It takes some time at the first video exactly because of what you said.