# Preload several videos while playing with mpmovieplayercontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to create an application which can play severals videos from URLs with no delay.

I successfully played videos using MPMoviePlayerController as I wished, but I faced a bigger problem.
The application should preload the next videos while playing the current one, but everything I tried didn't work.

Here's an example:

```
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://movon.co/files/TestMovie/01.mp4"]];

    NSLog(@"video Data: %@", videoData);

    NSString *videoString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:videoData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"video string: %@", videoString)
```

While I print videoData it seems the data is stored in the NSData, but when I'm trying to store it in NSString, the log prints (null).

I also thought of storing the videos in the documents of the app, but I read it might be a problem since those videos can't be deleted.

Is there any solution to my problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you create a bunch of MPMoviePlayers and then hide them until you need them?  Something like this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941734/putting-a-video-to-pause-state-before-playing/9073946#9073946

Comment: Well your code straight up makes no sense. You're retrieving video data, but then trying to turn that into a string. Videos are **not** strings!

Comment: @MikeAbdullah I guess you're right. But I just want to find a way to stream several videos using the MPMoviePlayerController. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Create multiple movie players, perhaps? Or download the files to disk.

Comment: If I'm downdloading the files to the device, I can delete them, right?